# Datasheet specifying less than 0.1 uF decoupling capacitors

Tags: decoupling-capacitor

The [lmh6550](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6550.pdf) fully differential amplifier "requires" capacitors as shown:

[image: decoupling]

The 0.1uF between rails makes sense, but I'm surprised at 10nF rather than 0.1uF to ground.  The part is relatively modern (mid-2000s) and anyway they're using 0.1uF elsewhere, so clearly the parts were available. They're also using 0603 in the reference design, so 0.1 uF would be a reasonable value given the footprint.

Is there an electrical reason for some of the capacitors to be smaller than 0.1uF?  I'm not very familiar with fully differential amplifiers, but it would create a lower AC impedance between the rails then to ground, although I don't know why that would be desirable.  Am I missing something or is this just some very specific cost optimization?

Answer (score 3):

A 0.01uF cap will have a higher self-resonant frequency than a 0.1uf capacitor. It is probably to keep a low impedance on the supply over a wider range of frequencies.

Notice that there is also a 0.1uF capacitor directly between the rails. I have had to use that on one occasion because of difficulty in decoupling the supply rails the usual way. (That was also with a National Semi opamp).

There are various ideas about the "best" way to arrange decoupling and some use multiple capacitors of different values to achieve the goal of a low impedance supply over a wide range of frequencies. Usually I find that a PCB layout with adjacent buried power and ground planes can do very well with the normal approach.

Comment: The 0.01uF will have a higher self-resonant frequency, but for 0603 will have a low impedance over a narrower range of frequencies:  https://imgur.com/a/s682afU  Do you mean the goal is to make the self-resonant frequency as high as possible even at the expense of impedance?

Comment: maybe use 0201 instead then.